# Force image to reload in Javascript on Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I have two totally separate images called lock-icon.png and lock-unlock-icon.png. On a certain event, I change an image's source in Javascript with

```
  document.getElementById("element").src = "/images/lock-unlock-icon.png";
```

This always works immediately on Firefox, but because I'm displaying a live HD video stream on the page that requires WebGL hardware acceleration, I need to use Chrome.

It sometimes works on Chrome, but pretty much never immediately; it seems like a random delay of at least a few seconds, at most never. If I examine the current "image location" of the icon after it should've changed, the url is the new, correct URL (which is obviously expected, because it's just querying the src property of the element).

What else should I be doing to force this image to reload in Chrome?

Comment: Your title is a little confusing. For a second I thought you were trying to override the browser's cache.

Comment: Sorry about the title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Load both images in separate divs, then just set display:inline on the currently viewable one, and display:none on the other. Then you can just toggle the two images by changing the CSS display property.

Comment: It's actually better to combine the two images into one large image and only show part of it, then use css to switch the part you're showing. This is called spriting, and reduces the total number of images your page needs to load, making it faster. Though, come to think of it, I don't know how to do that with image tags; it's more commonly used with background images.

Comment: Aah, why didn't I think of that! Thank you, fred!

user1618143: I've actually done it with image tags before, because I've made sprite-based video games in Javascript.... My head just wasn't on straight when I was making this application. But I honestly think Fred's answer is better for this particular application. I genuinely do want a separate image displayed.